# volley android the list size in my code return Zero

Tags: android

please anyone help me the list size in my code return Zero
**note:- list is  global variable when get the size is return zero**

```
   public void getdata(String cities) {
        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cities + "&APPID=8072ed7ede0fc9bcb8591a2a2eb90cfd";
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    CityWeather cityWeather = new CityWeather();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    cityWeather.setLonitude(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("coord").getDouble("lon")));
                    cityWeather.setLatitude(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("coord").getDouble("lat")));
                    cityWeather.setCityName(object.getString("name"));
                    cityWeather.setCurrentTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp")));
                    cityWeather.setPressure(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getInt("pressure")));
                    cityWeather.setHumidity(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getInt("humidity")));
                    cityWeather.setMinTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp_min")));
                    cityWeather.setMaxTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp_max")));
                    cityWeather.setWindSpeed(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("wind").getDouble("speed")));
                    cityWeather.setWindDegree(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("wind").getInt("deg")));
                    list.add(cityWeather);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

*Thanks for all*

Comment: where are you checking the list size, post whole code

Comment: i'm checking  on create method after call method getdata

Answer (score 1):

Volley is not synchronous, it takes the request and give you the callback when the request is completed. If you check the size after onResponse is called you will get the desired result

```
String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cities + "&APPID=8072ed7ede0fc9bcb8591a2a2eb90cfd";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                CityWeather cityWeather = new CityWeather();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                cityWeather.setLonitude(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("coord").getDouble("lon")));
                cityWeather.setLatitude(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("coord").getDouble("lat")));
                cityWeather.setCityName(object.getString("name"));
                cityWeather.setCurrentTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp")));
                cityWeather.setPressure(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getInt("pressure")));
                cityWeather.setHumidity(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getInt("humidity")));
                cityWeather.setMinTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp_min")));
                cityWeather.setMaxTemp(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp_max")));
                cityWeather.setWindSpeed(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("wind").getDouble("speed")));
                cityWeather.setWindDegree(String.valueOf(object.getJSONObject("wind").getInt("deg")));
                list.add(cityWeather);
                //Check list size here and do whatever you want with the list
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
```

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to ask